# Jquery - Case insensitive searching

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function search() {
    $("#myInput").keyup(function() {
        var value = this.value;

        $("table").find("tr").each(function(index) {
            if (index === 0) return;
            var id = $(this).find("td").first().text();
            $(this).toggle(id.indexOf(value) !== -1);
        });
    });
}
```

The above code is what I am using to search my table in HTML, however I cannot figure a way to ensure that however the value is typed, for example 'hello' or 'HeLLo' that it will still show up when searched. Essentially what I'm saying is - how do I make it so this code is case insensitive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make both lowercase or uppercase.

```
function search() {
    $("#myInput").keyup(function() {
        var value = this.value.toLowerCase();

        $("table").find("tr").each(function(index) {
            if (index === 0) return;
            var id = $(this).find("td").first().text().toLowerCase();
            $(this).toggle(id.indexOf(value) !== -1);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add a special method to search if one string contains another case insensitively ?:

Somewhere in the beginning of your code:

```
String.prototype.contains = function(src) {
    var srcUpper = src.toUpperCase();
    var thisUpper= this.toUpperCase();
    return srcUpper.indexOf(thisUpper) > -1;
}
```

And then use it where ever you want (you can change the method name of course.

And your code will become like this:

```
function search() {
    $("#myInput").keyup(function() {
        var value = this.value;

        $("table").find("tr").each(function(index) {
            if (index === 0) return;
            var id = $(this).find("td").first().text();
            $(this).toggle(id.contains(value));
        });
    });
}
```